# Why do we not contract 'Elle est' into 'Ell'est'?

Tags: orthographe, contractions

I noticed a pattern, which is when a word ending in 'e' is followed by a word beginning in 'e', the trailing 'e' (and space) in the first word is replaced by an apostrophe. For example:

> *Ce est* -> *C'est*

> *Le école* -> *L'école*

However, no one does this:

> *Elle est* -> *Ell'est*

Why?

Comment: In *l'école*, the apostrophe replaces *a* ("*la école*"), not *e*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that matter, why don't we contract every final *e* before a vowel?

On the one hand, you're right. The sound is dropped. *Elle est* is definitely two syllables, similarly to *l'école*.

On the other hand, the sound is typically not pronounced anyway. Since it's read as though it ends with a consonant, it doesn't feel like we need to mark the contraction. The words that we do that for are the ones where the schwa that gets dropped is the one and only vowel in the word: *le*, *de*, *ne*, *me*, *te*, *se*, *que*.

That said, there are exceptions and one could argue the opposite case. One point is that in some dialects, that final *e* does get pronounced, so there's a difference between *elle* on its own and in *elle est*. Another is that words like *puisque* and *jusque* get contracted even though the *e* is unstressed and has basically the same weight as that of *elle*.

At the end of the day, it comes down to the conventions in place when the orthography was standardized.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the final e by an apostrophe is done only on ONE syllable words like
ce, de, je, le, me, ne, que, se, te...

note that the e must be "neutral" = not accent, no é or è or ê and so on...

and the word must be "grammatical" words like pronouns... no name of generic objects, nor a proper noun

The rule works also for nobiliary particle
Le chevalier d’Artagnan

Comment: *Aujourd'hui*, *presqu'île*, *prud'homme*, *jusqu'alors*...

Comment: "aujourd'hui", "presqu'île", "prud'homme" are nouns of their own... but very interesting to signal.  By the way, "presqu'île" used to be written "presque île".
Even more interesting are words composed on "que" as you said : presque, jusque  like in 
jusqu'alors, presqu'à terme. But i was said it's wrong: we supposed to write presque à terme, presque aussi.

So "jusque" seems to be one of the exceptions.  
Although you may find  "jusques alors" for poetic/phonetic reasons.

Comment: puisque may be written puisqu' before: il, elle, on, un, une and most of times before: en, à, enfin, avec, aussi, aucun 
https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9P5031*

Comment: jusque may be written jusqu' before a word starting with a vowel or a mute h https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9J0414-A

Comment: preque may be found written as presqu' but it's wrong https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/presqu-ou-presque/ except in the noun "presqu'île"